# How to post NSNotificationCenter if orientation is landscape?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I would my view controller to post a notification used NSNotificationCenter if the orientation is landscape. I'm currently doing this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"change" object:self];
    }
}
```

I don't seem to get a response in my other file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning YES before you send your notification. It never gets called.